# In DNN, how to get base URL in Javascript Files

Tags: dotnetnuke, asp.net-web-api-routing

The Active Forums module is making AJAX calls to it's API but it doesn't work properly if the site is running in a sub-directory. How should it get the BaseURL that includes any subdirectories? (e.g example.com/intranet)

Sample call from a JS file (jquery.afFileUpload.js):

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/DesktopModules/ActiveForums/API/ForumService/GetUserFileUrl?FileId=' + fileid,
        beforeSend: sf.setModuleHeaders,
    })
```

I'm sure DNN has a proper way to get the Base URL (i.e. example.com/intranet) or to make the call in a way that handles this properly.

More info: https://github.com/ActiveForums/ActiveForums/issues/317

Answer (score 2):

```
url: window.location.hostname + '/DesktopModules/ActiveForums/...'
```

Happy DNNing!
Michael

Comment: window.location.hostname returns the full url of the current page (e.g. http://example.com/intranet/forums/afv/post/aft/13/aff/12) rather than just the base url.

Comment: Sorry, correction: window.location.hostname returns just the hostname (http://example.com/) instead of, example.com/intranet, which incluedes the subdirectory of the site.